# What plot type can I use for this stacked table?

Tags: python, matplotlib, group-by, seaborn, catplot

Newbie here ...
I obtained this dataframe using the `groupby` function. My aim is to plot the table in a way that will show the nested plots with the `ph` index as the pivot. Any other wiser methods (especially using `matplotlib` or `seaborn`) are also welcome.

```
df_ph = df2.groupby('pH').agg(['min','max','mean'])
```

```
{('Temperature (°C)', 'min'): {6.83: 22.5,
  6.89: 23.6,
  6.9: 22.5,
  6.92: 21.4,
  6.94: 23.2},
 ('Temperature (°C)', 'max'): {6.83: 22.5,
  6.89: 23.6,
  6.9: 22.5,
  6.92: 21.7,
  6.94: 23.2},
 ('Temperature (°C)', 'mean'): {6.83: 22.5,
  6.89: 23.6,
  6.9: 22.5,
  6.92: 21.549999999999997,
  6.94: 23.2},
 ('Turbidity (NTU)', 'min'): {6.83: 3.3,
  6.89: 4.6,
  6.9: 4.2,
  6.92: 4.7,
  6.94: 4.0},
 ('Turbidity (NTU)', 'max'): {6.83: 3.3,
  6.89: 4.6,
  6.9: 4.2,
  6.92: 4.9,
  6.94: 4.0},
 ('Turbidity (NTU)', 'mean'): {6.83: 3.3,
  6.89: 4.6,
  6.9: 4.2,
  6.92: 4.800000000000001,
  6.94: 4.0},
 ('Dissolved Oxygen (mg/L)', 'min'): {6.83: 6.1,
  6.89: 7.2,
  6.9: 6.0,
  6.92: 6.3,
  6.94: 6.6},
 ('Dissolved Oxygen (mg/L)', 'max'): {6.83: 6.1,
  6.89: 7.2,
  6.9: 6.0,
  6.92: 6.8,
  6.94: 6.6},
 ('Dissolved Oxygen (mg/L)', 'mean'): {6.83: 6.1,
  6.89: 7.2,
  6.9: 6.0,
  6.92: 6.55,
  6.94: 6.6},
 ('Conductivity (µS/cm)', 'min'): {6.83: 348,
  6.89: 320,
  6.9: 357,
  6.92: 362,
  6.94: 348},
 ('Conductivity (µS/cm)', 'max'): {6.83: 348,
  6.89: 320,
  6.9: 357,
  6.92: 363,
  6.94: 348},
 ('Conductivity (µS/cm)', 'mean'): {6.83: 348.0,
  6.89: 320.0,
  6.9: 357.0,
  6.92: 362.5,
  6.94: 348.0}}
```

I tried using

```
df.plot(xticks=df2['pH'], ylabel='pH')
```

but didn't get any reasonable plotting outcome.

Comment: `df2m = df2.melt(id_vars='pH')` and `g = sns.catplot(data=df2m, kind='bar', x='pH', y='value', col='variable', col_wrap=2)` or `kind='box'`.

Comment: In the future, it's better to post the raw data sample prior to any transformation.

Comment: Thank you..it worked. I only added `sharey=False`.